# SIGINT is not cleaned up in "${FUNCNAME[@]}"

Tags: bash, signals, function

Take the following script, interrupted by keyboard input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as shown:

```
$ function a() { echo "Performing"; sleep 10; echo "Performed"; }
$ a
Performing
^C
$ echo "${FUNCNAME[@]}"
a source
```

If we repeat the `SIGINT` during function `a` many times, we eventually end up with this scenario:

```
...

$ a
Performing
^C
$ a
Performing
^C
$ echo "${FUNCNAME[@]}"
a a a a a a a a a source
```

To demonstrate the issue, let's have another function, `b`, that gives an `message_error` function, also defined below:

```
$ function message_error() {
>   local MESSAGE="$1"
>
>   # FUNCNAME[1], as [0] is `message_error`, gets the calling function
>   echo "[[ ERROR ]] ${FUNCNAME[1]}: $MESSAGE"
>   echo "Rest of the stack: ${FUNCNAME[@]}"
>}
$ function b() { message_error "Oh no"; }
$ b
[[ ERROR ]] b: Oh no
Rest of the stack: message_error b a a a a a a a a a source
```

Even though the function is called in the `source`, `a` shows up as the calling function. As you can see, all these `a` functions were exited. However they remain in the FUNCNAME array.

Why is this? How can I remove it after SIGINT fails to remove it? Please note all functions are sourced from a large collection of commonly used functions, `~/.bash_functions`, if sourcing the functions affects how they interpret SIGINT.

Comment: Add a signal handler: `trap 'exit' SIGINT`

Comment: @SatoKatsura The script will then exit on `^C`. I don't want to tarnish the ability to interrupt a script mid-run, I simply want the exec trace to be an accurate representation of what's happening.

Comment: Did you try it? As @PSkocik says, this is only for interactive scripts.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yeah, I added `trap 'exit' SIGINT` one line below the shebang of `~/.bash_functions`. Then I saved the script and opened a new terminal window, and ran function `a`. The terminal window exited upon pressing `^C`. Sorry, forgot to mention that `~/.bash_functions` is sourced by `~/.bashrc`, which then makes use of the functions within it's script upon terminal start.

Comment: `trap ' ' SIGINT` solves the problem for me -- the func stack gets cleaned up then.

Comment: That's because `~/.bash_functions` is sourced in the current shell.  Try it the other way around: write a script, add the `trap`, and source `~/.bash_functions`.  Then run the script.

Comment: @PSkocik Then that won't interrupt the script...

Comment: @SatoKatsura We're talking about an interactive session here, no? Anyway, an empty handler will interrupt eitherr a session or a script. It will interrupt it and then return back to the main loop, and the return back to the main loop is what will restore the FUNCNAME stack.

Comment: @PSkocik An empty handler disables Ctrl-C for me in both interactive sessions and scripts. Which is pretty much what I expect.

Comment: IDK, even though `trap ' ' INT` solves it, it still might be worth it to report it. I think the cleanup should occur by default and `zsh` seems to agree.

Comment: @SatoKatsura `trap '' INT` == ignore SIGINT, `trap - INT` == restore default SIGINT handler, `trap ' ' INT` == handle sigint with an empty handler. I'm talking about the 3rd option here.

Comment: TIL: `trap ' ' SIGINT` is not the same as `trap '' SIGINT`.  How nice.

Comment: All of these solutions have introduced rather unusual behaviour for CTRL+C in my interactive shell session. Neither `''` or `' '`. I don't feel these solutions are therefore very usable. Honestly, I'd rather put up with a crappy non-clean exec trace than start interfering with signals if they're going to mess up how intuitive using the script is.

Answer (score 1):

Since `FUNCNAME` is a *read-only* array, there's probably no way to remove items in it.  It seems `unset FUNCNAME` sort of works, yet that also breaks `bash`'s special FUNCNAME behavior.

Prevention of `FUNCNAME` garbage can be done by using `trap`:

```
$ trap : SIGINT
$ function a() {  echo "Performing"; sleep 10; echo "Performed"; } 
$ a
Performing
^C
$ echo %"${FUNCNAME[@]}"%
%%
```

To disable the above prevention, do `trap - SIGINT`.